# How to order comments based on parent/child relationship

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have comments component, which renders comments. I can reply to a comment and it is stored as a child (parentId!=null and parentId=commentId);
In my reducer I would like to take this into account and display comments in hierarchical order, e.g.

1. comment1

   3. comment3 parentid1
2. comment2

   5. comment5
   6. comment6

So far I did as follows, but it does not work:

```
if (action.comment.parentId) {
                    let index = state.requestComments.findIndex(item =>
                        item.id === action.comment.parentId);
                     return {
                        ...state,
                        requestComments: [...state.requestComments.slice(
                            0, index),
                        action.comment,
                        ...state.requestComments.slice(index)
                        ],
                        error: null,
                        isCommentLoading: false
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        requestComments: [...state.requestComments,
                        action.comment],
                        error: null,
                        isCommentLoading: false
                    };
                }
```

Comment: Can explain how it's not working please?  What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Oh sorry, no errors, but the comments are not aligned per my requirements, they are added at the end.

Comment: You might want to add a console.log before each condition to check to see if it it's always falling back to the else statement.  If it's falling into your first condition then the comment shouldn't be appending to the end of your array.

Comment: You're using the === operator which will only return true if the *type* and *value* of both variables are the same, so make sure the type of item.id and action.comment.parentId are the same.  You can replace the findIndex condition with `parseInt(item.id, 10) === parseInt(action.comment.parentId, 10)`